# I'm attempting to render an array as a series of links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to do this in a view file:

```
<td><%= obj.user_ids.values.each {|user_id| link_to results_path(user_id)} %></td>
```

But it is displayed as the unchanged array.  Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<td>
  <% obj.user_ids.values.each do |user_id| -%>
    <%= link_to results_path(user_id) %>
  <% end -%>
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you, that does print out the links, but the array is displayed after.  I know in blocks you have to put a nil afterwords when using , but that isn't working here.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do. My understanding is that you are trying to render a list of links from an array. Can you explain a bit more how you expect the end result to look like? Thx.

Comment: @Jeremy If the array is displaying after, check to make sure that you are doing "<% obj.user_ids ..." and not "<%= obj.user_ids ...".

Answer (score 0):

Alternately you might try `collect`

```
<%= obj.user_ids.values.collect {|user_id| link_to results_path(user_id)}.join %>
```